# Accessing Nested JSON in YUI Table

Tags: javascript, json, yui

In my YUI application, I have the following valid JSON object returned from an AJAX request

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Henry Wood",
            "sport": {
                "sportId": 1,
                "sportName": "Basketball"
            }
     ]
}
```

In my response, I set the data for my table starting with `content`

```
dataTable.set('data', data.content);
```

however, when defining my columns I can't seem to retrieve `sportName` using dot notation (returns blank)

```
 { key: 'name', label: 'Name'},                   //returns Henry Wood
 { key: 'sport.sportName', label: 'Supply Chain', //doesn't work
```

Any ideas on how to access this nested property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the formatter option for column definitions like this

```
formatter: function (o) {
  return o.data.sport.sportName;
}
```

Column defs:

```
var cols = [{
    key: 'name',
    label: 'Name'
}, {
    label: 'Supply Chain',
    formatter: function (o) {
        return o.data.sport.sportName;
    }
}],
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/expfs6xn/**

Comment: I have a unique issue that arose when using this method. I've described it here if you want to take a crack at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461697/json-objects-incorrectly-appended-to-ajax-request